# Aligning text under input fields to the bottom left edge of the input

Tags: html, css

I have a input field that's centered in the middle of the screen. I also wanted to have the label under the input field but having trouble trying to figure out how to align the text to the bottom left of the input field instead of bottom center. The result im seeing is the label is moving too far to the left.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <input type="text" name="password" value=""><br>
  <label style="display:block; text-align:left">Password</label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: probably the easiet but not perfect solution to use a margin

Answer (score 2):

Set width to both input and label and make the label `display:inline:block`

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <input type="text" name="password" value=""style=" width:150px;"><br>
  <label style="display:inline-block; text-align:left;width:150px;" >Password</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try 2 separate div's inside the main div. Have a fixed/relative width of the parent div. Some thing like this.

```
<div style="text-align:center;width:120px">
<div><input name="password" type="text" value="" /></div>
<div style="display: block; text-align: left"><label>Password</label></div>
</div>
```

Comment: DIV is a block level element, no need for `display: block;`.

Comment: Right, totally agreed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply add a margin-right to the label.

Check out the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkdvc2o3/)

```
<body>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <input type="text" name="password" value=""><br>
  <label style="display:block; margin-right:110px;">Password</label>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

To the label, add

```
position: relative;
left: 10%;
```

Change the `left` value to whatever makes it line up.